# D3: Lag update of force layout hull on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

There is a lag update on my D3 force layout when it transitions between datasets:

When dataset changes from MORE links to LESS links dataset, the remnant convex hulls don't disappear on 1 click. User needs to click the update button twice for this code to run:

```
pathg.selectAll("path").remove();
```

[See JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2vh08e6y/9/)

After 1-Click transition from MORE hulls dataset to LESS hulls dataset:
[image: Remnant convex hulls]

What can possibly be wrong?? Does it have to do with D3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

Instead of

```
return "M" + 
    d3.polygonHull(d.values.map(function(i) { return [i.x, i.y]; }))
    .join("L") + "Z";
```

It should have been

```
var poly = d3.polygonHull(d.values.map(function(i) { return [i.x, i.y]; }));                                                
if (poly){
 return "M" + poly.join("L") + "Z";
}
```

Reason the `d3.polygonHull` for some array returns null, which caused the error.

Regarding `pathg.selectAll("path").remove();` you don't need to do it since exit will remove the unwanted links.

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9zfkhqga/)